# Django not serve admin static files (Apache, mod_wsgi)

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

I have a problem with admin static file (css, javascript, image)... I can't show this right template...

OS : Ubuntu 12.10 / Apache2 / mod_wsgi / Django 1.4

My apache config gile :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myhost.com/apache/buzzbal.wsgi

ServerName www.myhost.com
Alias /static /var/www/myhost.com/static/

<Directory /var/www/myhost.com/>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What's the exact problem? Does it not redirect away from django, or do you not have permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
Alias /static/ /var/www/myhost.com/static/
```

That is, trailing slash on both sub URL mount point as well as the target path.